# Slow fuzzy matching between two DataFrames

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have DataFrame A (`df_cam`) with cli id and origin:

```
cli id |            origin
------------------------------------
123    | 1234 M-MKT XYZklm 05/2016
```

And DataFrame B (`df_dict`) with shortcut and campaign

```
shortcut |         campaign
------------------------------------
M-MKT    | Mobile Marketing Outbound
```

I know that for example client with origin `1234 M-MKT XYZklm 05/2016` is actually from campaign `Mobile Marketing Outbound` because it contains key word `M-MKT`.

*Note that shortcut is a general key word, based on what the algorithm should decide. The origin can as well be `M-Marketing`, `MMKT` or `Mob-MKT`. I created the list of shortcuts manually by analyzing all the origins in the first place. I am also using regex to clean the `origin` before it is fetched to the program.*

I'd like to match customer origin with campaign through the shortcut and attach score to see the difference. As showed below:

```
cli id | shortcut |         origin            |        campaign           | Score
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123    | M-MKT    | 1234 M-MKT XYZklm 05/2016 | Mobile Marketing Outbound | 0.93
```

Below is my program which works, but is **really** slow. DataFrame A has ~400.000 rows and another DataFrame B has ~40 rows.

Is there a way I can make it faster?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
list_values = df_dict['Shortcut'].values.tolist()

def TopFuzzMatch(tokenA, dict_, position, value):
    """
    Calculates similarity between two tokens and returns TOP match and score
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    tokenA: similarity to this token will be calculated
    dict_a: list with shortcuts
    position: whether I want first, second, third...TOP position
    value: 0=similarity score, 1=associated shortcut
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    """
    sim = [(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, tokenA),x) for x in dict_]
    sim.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)
    return sim[position][value]

df_cam['1st_choice_short'] = df_cam.apply(lambda x: TopFuzzMatch(x['cli_origin'],list_values,0,1), axis=1 )
df_cam['1st_choice_sim'] = df_cam.apply(lambda x: TopFuzzMatch(x['cli_origin'],list_values,0,0), axis=1 )
```

Note that I'd like to calculate also 2nd and 3rd best match to evaluate the accuracy.

**EDIT**

I have found `process.ExtractOne` method, but the speed remains same.
So my code looks like this now:

```
def TopFuzzMatch(token, dict_, value):
    score = process.extractOne(token, dict_, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
    return score[value]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - after i clean the origin column with regex (no numbers and special characters), there are just a few hundred repeating distinct values, so I calculate the Fuzz algorithm just on those, which significantly improves the time.

```
def TopFuzzMatch(df_cam, df_dict):
    """
    Calculates similarity bewteen two tokens and return TOP match
    The idea is to do it only over distinct values in given DF (takes ages otherwise)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    df_cam: DataFrame with client id and origin
    df_dict: DataFrame with abbreviation which is matched with the description i need
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    """
    #Clean special characters and numbers
    df_cam['clean_camp'] = df_cam.apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '',x['origin']), axis=1)

    #Get unique values and calculate similarity
    uq_origin = np.unique(df_cam['clean_camp'].values.ravel())
    top_match = [process.extractOne(x, df_dict['Shortcut'])[0] for x in uq_origin]

    #To DataFrame
    df_match = pd.DataFrame({'unique': uq_origin})
    df_match['top_match'] = top_match

    #Merge
    df_cam = pd.merge(df_cam, df_match, how = 'left', left_on = 'clean_camp', right_on = 'unique')
    df_cam = pd.merge(df_cam, df_dict, how = 'left', left_on = 'top_match', right_on = 'Shortcut')

    return df_cam

df_out = TopFuzzMatch(df_cam, df_dict)
```